# two for loops, second only executes on first iteration python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a python noob, and I am attempting to compare values between lines in two files and output the "line name" followed by a 1 if the line is in the second file and a 0 if the line is missing from the second file. The first iteration returns a 1, because that line is in the second file, but for the remaning > 1,000 lines, they all return a 0 regardless of whether they are in the second list or not. It seems as though the second "for loop" only executes on the first iteration. Any ideas on why? Here is my code:

```
    import sys  

    file1 = sys.argv[1] 

    file2 = sys.argv[2]

    name = str(file2)

    f1 = open(file1, 'r') 
    f2 = open(file1, 'r')
    o1 = open((name + '1.txt'), 'w')

    for line in f1:
        name = line.strip('\r\n')
        count = 0
        for line1 in f2:
            if name == line1.strip('\r\n'):
                count += 1
                print (str(name) + '\t' + str(1))
                o1.write(str(name) + '\t' + str(1) + '\r\n')
        if count == 0:
            print (str(name) + '\t' + str(0))
            o1.write(str(name) + '\t' + str(0) + '\r\n')

    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    o1.close()
Any help is very much appreciated!
```

After some changes, this is what I have and it only returns '1s'

```
f1 = open(file1, 'r') #opens files for reading
f2 = open(file2, 'r')
o1 = open((name + '1.txt'), 'w')

f2s = {line.strip('\n') for line in f2}

for line in f1:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    count = 0
    if line in f2s:
        count += 1
        print (str(line) + '\t' + str(1))
        o1.write(str(line) + '\t' + str(1) + '\n')
    if count == 0:
        print (str(line) + '\t' + str(0))
        o1.write(str(line) + '\t' + str(0) + '\n')
```

Embarrassing, I was opening the same file twice. Rookie.

Comment: A few comments: `name` is already a string, so no need for `str(name)`. Similarly, `"1"` is nicer than `str(1)`. Then, `\n` is newline in Python; it will automatically convert that to  `\r\n` on Windows, so no need to do that (it might even hurt to do so).

Comment: @TimPietzcker: +1. Except that if you're reading a Windows text file on Unix, it may be useful. (But the OP looks like he's using Py3, so there are better ways to do that.)

Comment: Also, you probably means `f2 = open(file2)`, not `f2 = open(file1)`, right? Otherwise, every line in f1 is also in f2, since they're the same file… And you should consider using `with open(file1) as f1, open(file) as f2:` instead of explicit `close` statements, because it's easier to read and harder to get wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f2` is an iterator over your second file, and when that has been read, it's exhausted.

You *can*  reset the iterator `f2.seek(0, 0)`, but that's not really the best way to go.

Better put all the values from `f2` into a `set` and then iterate over `f1` only once:

```
f2s = {line.strip('\n') for line in f2}

for line in f1:
    name = line.strip('\n') # No need for \r\n
    if name in f2s:
        # etc.
```

If you need to count the number of occurences of each line from `f1` in `f2`, then you can use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
f2c = Counter(line.strip('\n') for line in f2)

for line in f1:
    name = line.strip('\n')
    if name in f2c:
        count = f2c[name]
```

Comment: +1 for replacing the whole inner loop with `set.__contains__`.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your reply. I have made the changes, but now, when I run my code, it returns all ones, even though I know that the values are not all in the set. I've added my updated my code to my original post, any ideas?

Comment: @Micrasema: You're opening the same file twice.

Comment: @Tim, wow, that's embarrassing, I'm sorry. Whoops. You've been very helpful

Comment: @Micrasema: abarnert noticed that much earlier than me (see his second comment to your question).

Answer (score 1):

The first time you execute `for line in f2:`, it goes through every line in `f2`, leaving the current file pointer at the end of the file. So, the second time, it starts from the end of the file, and goes through all 0 of the remaining lines…

If you want to repeat that, there are a few ways to do it. You could move the `f2 = open(file1, 'r')` into the outer loop. Or you could reset the file with `f2.seek(0, 0)`. Or you could use `itertools.tee`.

But, unless you really don't have the memory to hold the whole file at once, you probably want to read the lines into a `list` the first time and just iterate that `list`:

```
l2 = list(f2)
# ...
for line in f1:
    # ...
    for line1 in l2:
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) helps compare lines and perhaps you can leverage that.