# Python - 2nd 'for' loop in function not working

Tags: python, for-loop

I may be missing the obvious here, and if so please excuse the noob (which I am) question. I am trying to iterate through the lines in a text file. The first `for` works fine; however, the 2nd `for` does not. The `print(eachLine)`command does not print anything, and the result of the `newY` list is a blank list (as it has been initialized). All the debugging I have done (below is just the latest) points out to the 2nd `for` not being accessed at all.  What am I missing here?

Edit: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737980/two-for-loops-second-only-executes-on-first-iteration-python), but in that one there are *nested* loops and the mistake is that the user was referring to the *same* line in the *same file* in *nested* loops. I am trying to loop through the file all over again, from scratch.

```
import os
os.chdir ('d:\Documente\python tests')

def plotRegression(myFile):
    lineCounter=0
    sumX=0
    sumY=0
    sumXY=0
    sumX2=0
    newY=[]

    for eachLine in myFile:
        coords=eachLine.split()
        lineCounter=lineCounter+1
        sumX=sumX+float(coords[0])
        sumY=sumY+float(coords[1])
        sumXY=sumXY+float(coords[0])*float(coords[1])
        sumX2=sumX2+float(coords[0])**2

    avgX=sumX/lineCounter
    avgY=sumY/lineCounter
    m =(sumXY-lineCounter*avgX*avgY)/(sumX2-lineCounter*avgX**2)

    for eachLine in myFile:
        print (eachLine)
        coords=eachLine.split()
        newY.append(avgY+m*(coords[0]-avgX))

    return (avgX, avgY,sumXY, sumX2, m, newY)


def Main():
    dataFile = open("labdata.txt","r")
    print (plotRegression(dataFile))
    dataFile.close()


Main()
```

Comment: Please make a **minimal example**. None of the sumX/avgX calculations are relevant to your problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - When posting, I did not know what the problem was, so I gave as much info as possible. Looks like I got some additional hints because of that. I won't edit the question now, otherwise part of the answer will not make sense. But nevertheless, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: You're making a very valid point :) but remember: usually, you'd try to narrow down your problem yourself before asking, so removing the calculation from your code would have been my first attempt at solving. Still: Gave your comment an upvote, because it's very sensible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to *rewind* your file read position to the start, using [`file.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek):

```
myFile.seek(0)
```

Files are streams; reading from a file or writing to it advances a file pointer to a new position. Iterating over a file to read from it line by line is no exception. Once you've read all the lines in a file, the file position is left all the way at the end and iterating again won't produce any additional information.

It'd be a better idea to process all the information from the file and store it in memory, reading just *once*. File reading is a slow process, compared to accessing the same information in memory. In this case, you only need to use the first value from each line; store that when reading in the first loop:

```
x_coords = []
for eachLine in myFile:
    x, y = (float(c) for c in eachLine.split())
    lineCounter += 1
    x_coords.append(x)
    sumX += x
    sumY += y
    sumXY += x * y
    sumX2 += x ** 2

avgX = sumX / lineCounter
avgY = sumY / lineCounter
m = (sumXY - lineCounter * avgX * avgY) / (sumX2 - lineCounter * avgX ** 2)

for x in x_coords:
    newY.append(avgY + m * (x - avgX))
```